# Design issue for android app, for few phone devices like Samsung Note 2 and Galaxy S4

Tags: android

I have been working on an app for Android OS. The app is pretty much complete, but the issue I am facing is the screen sizes. There are several devices on which the app is working properly with the correct design in place, and a few other devices on which is it not.

The app design is working fine on:
Samsung Galaxy Grand (Quattro) - Screen Size 5.0"
Samsung Galaxy Grand - Screen Size 5"
Samsung Duos 7.62 - Screen Size 4.0"
HTC One V - Screen Size 3.7"

And the app design is not working properly on:
Samsung Note 2
Samsung Galaxy S4
HTC Sensation

These are the phones I was able to test so far for the app.

```
We have different design sizes for:
320 x 480   -- mdpi
480 x 800   -- hdpi
640 x 960   -- 
720 x 1280  -- xhdpi
1080 x 1920 -- xxhdpi.
```

The home screen of the app has 6 rows. as shown in the image below[image]

For Samsung note 2 and S4, the screen exceeds the mobile screen, like the last tab is shown only half, where as in the HTC Sensation, the tabs do not completely fill the screen, leaving 1/4 of the screen blank.

Please help with your suggestions. I need to know is I need to design the screens for some other size as well, what should be that screen size. or what am I doing wrong right now.

Thanks in advance,
Zeeshan

Comment: Mind to post some code? :)

Answer (score 1):

is it the height of the rows that's a problem for you?

If you would like all of the rows to fit onto the screen, regardless of the screen size, you can use [layout weights](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight). Specify the height of each row as 0dp, and then use layout_weight to weight them. If all of the rows have the same weight, they will be spaced evenly. Below, I have given the third row a higher weight (2 rather than 1) as it looks bigger in your screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_four"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_five"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <View android:id="@+id/row_six"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your layout

let's consider the horizontal rows are linearlayouts

> Use the layout_weight property to "1" ( layout_weight = "1" )

it spaces all the layouts to be fit in the screen.

Make sure the logos in the app are medium sized so that they do not exceed take more space. They can create misalignment too...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Note 2 comes under xhdpi category and Samsung Galaxy S4 comes under xxhdpi category and plus these phones have a large screen so it is better you provide a different layout for such phones

```
layout-large

layout-xlarge
```

and respective drawable folder as well..

```
 drawable-large 

drawable-xlarge
```

then whenever you run the app ...android automatically allots according to resources given or else will take from  the default  folder